# Get last step in component wizard

Tags: asp.net, wizard, icollection

C# Wizard control has the event *ActiveStepChanged* that is triggered when we move through the steps of the wizard. The current step is stored in the property called *ActiveStepIndex*. I need to retrieve the step immediately preceding the current *ActiveStepIndex*.

I'm trying this way but without results up to now:

```
ICollection s = wizTransferSheet.GetHistory(); 
IList steps = s as IList;
WizardStep lastStep = steps[steps.Count].Name;
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how complex your wizard is, that can be tricky sometimes. You can't always use the `ActiveStepIndex`. Luckily, the wizard control logs a history of the steps visited, and you can leverage this to retrieve the last step that was visited:

You can use this function to get the last step that was visited:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the last wizard step visited.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private WizardStep GetLastStepVisited()
{
    //initialize a wizard step and default it to null
    WizardStep previousStep = null;

    //get the wizard navigation history and set the previous step to the first item
    var wizardHistoryList = (ArrayList)wzServiceOrder.GetHistory();
    if (wizardHistoryList.Count > 0)
        previousStep = (WizardStep)wizardHistoryList[0];

    //return the previous step
    return previousStep;
}
```

Here's some sample code from one of our wizards. The wizard is pretty complex, and there is a lot of potential branching based on what the user does. Because of that branching, navigating the wizard can be a challenge. I don't know if any of this will be useful to you, but I figured it was worthwhile including it just in case.

```
/// <summary>
/// Navigates the wizard to the appropriate step depending on certain conditions.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="currentStep">The active wizard step.</param>
private void NavigateToNextStep(WizardStepBase currentStep)
{
    //get the wizard navigation history and cast the collection as an array list 
    var wizardHistoryList = (ArrayList)wzServiceOrder.GetHistory();

    if (wizardHistoryList.Count > 0)
    {
        var previousStep = wizardHistoryList[0] as WizardStep;
        if (previousStep != null)
        {
            //determine which direction the wizard is moving so we can navigate to the correct step
            var stepForward = wzServiceOrder.WizardSteps.IndexOf(previousStep) < wzServiceOrder.WizardSteps.IndexOf(currentStep);

            if (currentStep == wsViewRecentWorkOrders)
            {
                //if there are no work orders for this site then skip the recent work orders step
                if (grdWorkOrders.Items.Count == 0)
                    wzServiceOrder.MoveTo(stepForward ? wsServiceDetail : wsSiteInformation);
            }
            else if (currentStep == wsExtensionDates)
            {
                //if no work order is selected then bypass the extension setup step
                if (grdWorkOrders.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
                    wzServiceOrder.MoveTo(stepForward ? wsServiceDetail : wsViewRecentWorkOrders);
            }
            else if (currentStep == wsSchedule)
            {
                //if a work order is selected then bypass the scheduling step
                if (grdWorkOrders.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                    wzServiceOrder.MoveTo(stepForward ? wsServicePreview : wsServiceDetail);
            }
        }
    }
}
```